# JQuery Mobile 1.4.5 in Asp.Net MVC 5

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am developing application in ASP.Net MVC 5 with jquery mobile 1.4.5. I have downloaded JQuery mobile 1.4.5 package and copied all related files in Script and Content folder.

Now when I am running application, it is showing ajax-loader.gif on every page. in middle of the page.

I am unable to find out the reason, why it is showing ajax-loader.gif.

Any help?

Comment: Can you inspect the page, there might be some log messages in the console? I would use the debug option [link] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FQKvro1Wz-E ). Otherwise I would be checking for the call to the init function. Does it have a callback function? Have you call it?

Comment: I did not do anything. I just included files and ran it.

Comment: maybe that's why..  it would be good if you check the structure of your page. This might help. [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj650891.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The bug produced because I added both **jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js** and **jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js** in the project.

I removed the minified version and everything is running fine.